# How to group Checkboxes in a GridView so I can display a message when all CheckBoxes in a group are checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView that displays potential duplicate reports. The reports are grouped together by an ID field and this was done in SQL. ID 1 has 2 potential duplicate reports ID 2 has two potential duplicates.

There is a checkbox control at the end of each row that will deactivate the duplicate report. I want to know how to display a message when all the checkboxes in ID 1 are checked so that all copies of the report are not deactivated. I am using VB.NET and ASP.NET. Can I do this in JavaScript?

[Snippet of the GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58on1.png)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deactivate">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`
```

Comment: Try looping through all the rows in the grid while evaluating the Checkbox controls you ask about.  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows

Comment: There should be quite a few similar questions, here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/923424/2953322. Have a go in Javascript and ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, just count each checkbox that is checked and see if the number checked equals the number of rows in the grid.

```
    Dim X as Integer = 0
    For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView_MyGrid.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
        if cb.Checked = True
            X+=1
        End If
    Next
    If GridView_MyGrid.Rows,Count = X
        ' They're all checked ...
    End If
```